# User inputing 10 integers.Need to counter to count interations and largest integer

Tags: ruby, eclipse

puts 'Please enter 10 numbers one at a time.'

value_list = []             #stores numbers in an array

count = 0
uicomp = 0

while count < 10
  ui=int(raw_input('Please enter an integer number | ' + str(10-count) + ' remain: '))       #input countdown display
  if ui>uicomp;          #check current input to see if it's larger than the previous
   uicomp=ui             # Store variable rebind
    count += 1           # Iteration incremental
  end
end

10.times do                 #can also use i in 1..10 do
  value_list << gets.chomp.to_i
end

puts "Largest integer from the numbers entered is: #{value_list.max}"

Comment: `int(raw_input `? Looks like Python?

Comment: Please edit to make the title more meaningful and to remove "Noob to Ruby", and state your question in the body. If you look at other titles here, you will see that none resemble yours in the faintest.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what you want but it should solve your problem:

```
puts 'Please enter 10 numbers one at a time.' 

max = 0

1.upto(10) do |count|
  puts "Please enter an integer number | #{10-count} remain:" #input countdown display
  num = gets.chomp.to_i

  if num > max #check current input to see if it's larger than the previous
    max = num # Store variable rebind
  end

end

puts "Largest integer from the numbers entered is: #{max}"
```

Comment: I defined count = 0. but its not counting down when I enter a integer

Comment: Make sure count is defined outside of the loop.